# Edit file on kubernetes image before starting it

Tags: kubernetes, edit

I have an image called `http` which has a file called `httpd-isec.conf`. I'd like to edit `httpd-isec.conf` before the image is started by kubernetes. Is that possible?

Would `initContainers` and mounting the image work in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Images are immutable. What you can do is use an init container to copy the file to an emptyDir volume, edit it, and then mount that volume over the original file in the main container.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds simple enough to do the trick. I actually did it before saw your answer by placing env variable names within the file and then using `- env` to populate the variables based on my needs.

Comment: That is much preferable when you can do it :) Keep the initContainer trick for when you have no other options, it makes debugging a million times more annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes please add a boot script in your image to edit the file .
You could also create a custom image and put you http image as base image for it and edit the file on init